# Geolocation and PubNub work on the browser but not on android

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, geolocation, pubnub

I have a code for my application (in which I am using Apache Cordova) in PubNube HTML5 JavaScript geolocation, which identifies the user's location in real time, however, this code works perfectly in the browser, but when I transform the file of Apache Cordova in APK by Android Studio, it ends up not working in APK, so I think it is easy to solve, since it is working on one platform and the other is not.

My Android Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="org.apache.cordova" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

My Javascript Code

```
 const clientUUID = PubNub.generateUUID();

   var pubnub = new PubNub({
    publishKey: *****,
    subscribeKey: ****,
    secretkey: ****
  });

if ('geolocation' in navigator) {
    const watcher = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position){
        // sets default position to your position
      var latitude = position.coords["latitude"];
      var longitude = position.coords["longitude"];
      var altitude = 0;
      console.log(position); 
      console.log({"lat":latitude, "lng":longitude, "alt":0}); 

      var newMessage = {
          lat: latitude,
          lng: longitude
      }

      pubnub.publish(
        {
          channel: "******",
          message: newMessage
        },
        function(status, response) {
          console.log(status, response);
          console.log("Submit");
          console.log(newMessage);
        }
      );
    }, function(error){
        console.log(error)
    }, {enableHighAccuracy: true, maximumAge: 30000, timeout: 30000})
}
```

Comment: It's probably not PubNub since it works on browser but if you [enable PubNub SDK logging](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/phonegap-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk-troubleshooting-guide) it might reveal some clues. You can submit logs to [PubNub Support](https://support.pubnub.com) for some free assistance.

Comment: Before you do PubNub troubleshooting, try adding this: Put these permission outside the <application> tag, preferable before the tag in the AndroidManifest.xml.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` and 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>`
```

Comment: I just tried these two alternatives, but without success

Comment: Alternatives? Not sure what you mean. Did you add both permissions? Were you able to produce logs?

Comment: Just checking in to see if you were able to resolve? Did you contact PN Support?